If $\zeta(5)=\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $b\neq p^k$
If $\zeta(5)=\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$ then prove that $b\neq p^k$ where $p$ is any prime and $k\in\mathbb{N}$
Take $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(a,b)=1$. Now if $b=p^k$ then $$p^k\zeta(5)=a$$ So, by euler product of Riemann zeta function which is valid for $\Re(s)>1$ we have, $$p^k\prod_{P \ prime}\frac{1}{1-P^{-5}} =a$$ So we obtain $$p^k\prod_{P \ prime}\frac{P^5}{P^5-1} =a$$
$$p^k\prod_{P \ prime}\left(1+\frac{1}{P^5-1}\right) =a$$
Any help would be highly appreciated.

What have you tried? What issues you encountered?

@Zima Thanks for the comment. I could not think of a solution. I tried a lot

Including in your post some of your work could help others approaching the problem, and will get your question more attention.

@Max Put all you've tried in your question, so one can suppport you !

@EDX Sorry but I am running short of ideas.

Ok @Max, may you look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function here, Euler's products section. Could give you some ideas.

@EDX Thanks. I have edited my question accordingly.

@Max yes at least It gives an attemps :)
